# Whats the difference between React 18's new { cache } and Next.js deduping?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, caching, server-side-rendering

In the context of calling a getCurrentUser function in a root layout.jsx and a sub-route layout.jsx file, and you load the sub-route page which in turn renders both layouts in a single render pass:

- What would be the difference between the built in Next.js de-duping feature for API calls and React's new cache feature with import { cache } from 'react'?

They both stop redundant API calls in the same render pass and store it in a cache. Is using both then redundant? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

When making requests using the `fetch` API within the server component (in your case, multiple `layout.jsx` files in your Next.js project), it's crucial to deduplicate the requests sent to the backend data source:

[image]

(The image is from Next.js documentation: [Caching in Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching)
)

React patches `globalThis.fetch` on the server side, so that React can handle the deduplication for you automatically: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b09e102ff1e2aaaf5eb6585b04609ac7ff54a5c8/packages/react/src/ReactFetch.js#L130

> Note that React only patches `globalThis.fetch` on the server side (during SSR or SSG). React does not alter `globalThis.fetch` on the client side (i.e., within browsers).

However, not all data fetching occurs through `fetch`. You might be using an ORM within your Server Components:

```
import db from 'your-favorite-orm';

const getUserInfoByUid = (uid) => db.findOne().where({ uid: { $eq: uid } });

const ServerComp = async () => {
const uid = cookies().get('uid');
    const userInfo = await getUserInfoByUid(uid);
    return <div />;
};
```

In this scenario, React can't automatically deduplicate the `getUserInfoByUid` call for you. You'll need to manually opt-in for deduplication by using the `React.cache` API:

```
import db from 'your-favorite-orm';
import { cache } from 'react';

const getUserInfoByUid = cache((uid) => db.findOne().where({ uid: { $eq: uid } }));
```

The `React.cache` API only handles requests for duplication. It does not persist the response on the disk, so it can't be reused for different requests (100 page visits will trigger 100 queries).

Next.js also offers a `React.cache`-like API [`unstable_cache`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/unstable_cache) (as the name implies, it is currently in an unstable state) that you can access using `import { unstable_cache } from 'next/cache'`.

```
import { unstable_cache } from 'next/cache';
const getTodayTrendRepo = unstable_cache(() => {
    // ...
});
```

Like `React.cache`, it also deduplicates requests. However, unlike `React.cache`, `next/cache` persists the response on the disk, so it can reduce requests sent to the backend data source from **all visitors** (100 page visits will only trigger 1 query).

In general, you should use `React.cache` in the following scenarios:

- When you're fetching data on the client side (within browsers)

  - React doesn't modify `globalThis.fetch` on the client side, so it won't automatically deduplicate your fetch requests.
- When you're fetching data on the server side but not using the `fetch` API

  - On the server side, React will automatically deduplicate your fetch requests by modifying `globalThis.fetch`. However, data fetching performed through other methods (like an ORM, for instance) cannot be deduplicated automatically and needs to be manually opted into using `React.cache`.

You should use `next/cache` when you're fetching data that is computationally expensive yet immutable.

Comment: Thanks for your length answer. In my case I am using Ky wrapper in RSCs in App Router and redirecting requests from my next frontend to my server. In which case I would not need to use React.cache by your answer?

Comment: It seems the wasnt working properly with Ky unless I use `React.cache`